# png compression in opencart not working

Tags: php, opencart

I've been searching and trying to figure out why I can't get png image compression to work for an opencart 1.5 site I'm working on.

On line 46 of library/image.php I modified the imagepng function to use compression 9 instead of the default 0 and it had no affect on my images. I deleted the images from the fileserver and they just repopulate with the exact same file size/quality.

Anyone know how I can get the file sizes of my images down? A 1000x750px image is over 2M and it's killing my load times.

Thank!

Comment: "no affect" -- as in, the file sizes _seem_ the same? or are they byte-for-byte identical? If you insert debugging `print` statements around the change you made, do you see if your code gets executed at all?

Comment: They are byte-for-byte identical. I actually commented out the line and the images are still created. There are other functions in the file which do resizing but none of them use imagepng (the images are being resized as well). Here is a link to the file in question http://code.google.com/p/opencart/source/browse/trunk/upload/system/library/image.php?r=577

Comment: Perhaps the images aren't going through that `save()` function. Double-check that that code is actually being executed.

Comment: Are you on a shared host or dedicated?

Comment: Just so this isn't left hanging; I wasn't able to find a solution and ended up just going back to jpgs. I'm on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

> I modified the imagepng function to use compression 9 instead of the
>   default 0 and it had no affect on my images.

This actually worked for me. I changed it from **"0"** to **"9"** and cleared the cache images and the files sizes were about **65% less**.

Answer (score 0):

You can just download an image compression extension instead of editing source code because when you upgrade your changes will be lost.